# Hello world Phonegap Android App not loading

Tags: android, cordova, dojox.mobile

Yesterday was my day 1 of phonegap. Tried setting exactly as per the wiki . When it tries to run, the application not getting loading in AVD device throwing out this message  "Unfortunately App has stopped".

Following are my configuration

1. Eclipse 4.2 juno release
2. Android android-sdk_r18-windows
3. Phone gap tried both 1.7 and 1.5

Steps followed ..

1. created the project
2. copied xml to res , jar to lib folder and js file and index.html file in www folder.

Am I missing something out here .. Tried different apps lot of times . Please help

Regards

Hashique

Comment: Can you post the logcat exactly?

Comment: @Coder_sLaY  please find the traces.txt                                        DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x409c1460 self=0x12810
  | sysTid=252 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074082952
  | schedstat=( 410777682 2056528775 359 ) utm=31 stm=10 core=0
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:2200)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4024)
  at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you need to create `libs` folder instead of `lib` folder, as the latest android SDK is been updated from r17. So just create a libs folder and place the jar file in it. Then automatically it will be added to build path and you will not get this error....

Answer (score 1):

They have Eclipse plugin to generate initial setup for PhoneGap Android. Follow this.
Anyway I recommend you to add plugin after you setup your helloworld yourself. Because you need to understand whats going on. Anyway if nothing works use this.

http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/